# PHP Seconds to MM:SS Function

Tags: php, function

Currently I use the following javascript function to conver seconds to minutes and seconds.

```
function fmtMSS(s){return(s-(s%=60))/60+(9<s?':':':0')+s}
```

If I pass it 235 it returns `3:55`

I've tried to convert it to php, but passing 235 to it I get `55`

What have I done wrong ?

```
function fmtMSS($s){
        return($s-($s%=60))/60+(9<$s?':':':0')+$s;
    };
    echo fmtMSS(235);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `date ('i:s', 235)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong logic part in your PHP version. Take a look at this:

```
function fmtMSS($s){
    return(($s-($s%60))/60).(9<$s?':':':0').$s%60;
};
echo fmtMSS(235);
```

Sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/163b767d435cf9db9058d03e95b873fb07e3fcbd

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to do it in a one-liner unless its the easiest and most readable way. Don't sacrifice readable code for shorter code.

The below function is the simplest and easiest way to convert seconds into a `minute:seconds` format. The reason for not using `date("H:i", $s)` (which would yield the same result) is that it will not scale well, and return incorrect results if `$s` ever gets high.

Divide by 60, floor it - that will get you the minutes. Multiply it by 60 and subtract it from `$s`, and you have your seconds.

```
function fmtMSS($s){
    $minutes = floor($s/60); 
    $seconds = $s-$minutes*60; 
    return "$minutes:$seconds";
};
echo fmtMSS(235); // 3:55
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/GQs7j)

The reason your original code doesn't work, is because you're using `+` to join strings (as you would in JavaScript). However, in PHP, one uses `.` to contact two strings. The logic also seems to be a bit incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function fmtMSS($s){
    $min = floor($s/60);        
    $sec = $s%60;
    return $min.':'.$sec;
};
echo fmtMSS(235);
?>
```

Use this code- i have just edited your function.

for short:- echo gmdate("i:s", 235);